# Radeon Graphics loud fan, unable to boot

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, power-supply, fan

I have an ASUS P6TD Deluxe with a Core i7 CPU (950 @ 3.07 GHZ), 6 GB Ram.
I am running a PSU ANTEC 550 Watts. On it, I am running a quite new Radeon R9 290X.
The system is booting of a Kingston SSD, for now all other periphery is disconnected (except mouse, keyboard & Network).

This system was freshly setup about 2 weeks ago from scratch with Windows 8.1, freshly formatted HD etc. I have been running high-performance games, the system was basically running 24h/d for 2 weeks without any big problems.

Yesterday night I switched it off, and when I switched it on this morning, it would not boot, but the graphics card fan goes into overdrive. Black screen.

I have tried a more powerful, 950w PSU. I always connect both PCI-Express power supplies to the card.

I have tried another Radeon Card, an older HD6870, same result of loud fans and no screen. This card has been in place before the newer R9 came in and also always works perfectly.

Now I have tried a very old, Gigabyte GeForce 7300 GS (passively cooled) and the system starts normally.

I am doubting that 2 graphics cards get roasted at the same time. Is there anything on the Motherboard, CPU or RAM that would allow me to run a low-performance GPU but not a stronger one?

How can I debug this? Anything else that I can try?

Comment: @AndréDaniel I exchanged the motherboard and it's working now, so your suggestion was most likely the correct one. If you want to post that as an answer, I can accept it then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fan running at full speed on a graphics card indicates that the card didn't boot (thus the logic that measures the temperature and adjusts the fan speed isn't working yet), it can happen if the motherboard is damaged (no power on the PCI-e bus ?), no power on the card's external connectors, or the card being damaged.

Your old card may still work at a lower speed (using less PCI-e lanes) than the newer cards that require more - maybe your motherboard still has one PCI-e lane working, that's enough for the old card but not enough for the newer cards.

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar issue that was the result of the DVI cable having a short. If you have another cable try that as well as testing different outputs on the card to see if that fixes it.

Comment: Thanks, I tried Displayport as well as HDMI, but both seem to have the same issue.